# How to edit a formula for a range of cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have linked two excel worksheets together so whatever data I input into worksheet 1, will appear in the proper cells of worksheet 2. Next month, I will receive a new worksheet which will have a new source name.

How do I edit the new source name into worksheet 2 so that I don't have to copy+paste repeatedly for the entire sheet?

For example, currently the source name is:

```
"='C:\Users\Sue''s\Desktop\[DEXCOM_GSPM 0113.xls]GSPM'!$S$6:$S$8"
```

The new worksheet will be named DEXCOM_GSPM 0213.

How I update this?

Comment: Find/Replace (by Formula) will take care of this for you

Comment: @mcalex worth an answer!

Comment: Find/Replace is good. I would also take a look at array formulas.

Answer (score 5):

To achieve what you want, do the following:

1. Open your file in Excel - that one which has now `='C:\Users\Sue''s\Desktop[DEXCOM_GSPM 0113.xls]GSPM'!$S$6:$S$8` formula.
2. Open `Replace` dialog via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
3. Press `>>Options` and set up the options as on the screen (in case you want to correct formulas for the **entire** workbook - select `Workbook` for `Within:`):

[image: Replace options]

Now press `Replace All` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you want it to cover future changes as well, could be to use INDIRECT().

If you put the name of the file (including file extension) into cell A1 and change the formula to this:

```
"=INDIRECT("'C:\Users\Sue''s\Desktop\["&A1&"]GSPM'!$S$6:$S$8")"
```

Then for any future filename changes you'd just change the filename in cell A1 (or wherever you decide to put it). This solution may not be suitable for your needs in that the book you're referring to with the INDIRECT() function would need to be open in order to calculate correctly, but if you have to refer to multiple files or the filename changes frequently it might be useful to you.